# handling a webservice responce with ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, api

I am collecting a response from a web service in a Rails' app with

```
response = #api.sql_data
```

This causes `response` to equal the following.

```
response
  #=> { "success"=>true, "totalcount"=>10, "rows"=>[
  #     { "ID"=>"0001", "CODE"=>"0000001", "CODE_1"=>"Alpha",
  #       "NAME"=>"Alpha", "Balance"=>"0" },
  #     { "ID"=>"0002", "CODE"=>"0000002", "CODE_1"=>"Beta",
  #       "NAME"=>"Beta", "Balance"=>"0" },
  #     { "ID"=>"0003", "CODE"=>"0000003", "CODE_1"=>"Charlie",
  #       "NAME"=>"Charlie", "Balance"=>"0"},
  #     ...
  #     ]
  #   }
```

I have created the following method:

```
def format_response(response)   
  response['rows'].map do |row|
    { id: row[0],
      code: row[1],
      code1: row[2],
      balance: row[4] }   
  end.uniq { |x| x[:code1] }
end
```

When I execute this method for the above value of `response`, I obtain the following.

```
format_response(response)
  #=> [{:id=>nil, :code=>nil, :code1=>nil, :balance=>nil}]
```

This is incorrect. I would like this expression to return the following.

```
{"ID"=>"0001", "CODE"=>"0000001", "CODE_1"=>"Alpha", "NAME"=>"Alpha", "Balance"=>"0"}
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: HaCos, I trust my edit did not change your question. If it did please accept my apology and either edit my edit or roll-back to your original question. (Click "edited" to bring up the rollback option.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response['rows']` contains an array of hashes. Hashes in ruby are not associative arrays so you cannot get the first key by `hash[0]`.

```
def format_response(response)   
  response['rows'].map do |row|
    {   
      id: row["ID"],
      code: row["CODE"],
      code_1: row["CODE_1"],
      balance: row["BALANCE"] 
    }   
  end.uniq { |x| x[:code1] }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Each row is a hash so you need to access its elements by name not by index (as you would with an array). The following should work:

```
def format_response(response)   
  formatted_response = response['rows'].map do |row|
    { id: row['ID'],
      code: row['CODE'],
      code1: row['CODE_1'],
      balance: row['balance'] }   
  end
  formatted_response.uniq { |x| x[:code1] }
end
```